# Gulp won't recompile sass when changes are made

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

I have created some tasks to recompile the sass with browser-sync whenever changes are made.
My gulp file is as follows:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    var files = [
        './*.html',
        './css/*.css',
        './img/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
        './js/*.js'
    ];

    browserSync.init(files, {
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });

});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', function() {
    gulp.start('sass:watch');
}));
```

I am using node version 12.16.1, gulp-sass version 4.1.0, gulp-cli version 2.3.0, gulp local version 4.0.2 and browser-sync version 2.26.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
// gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', function() {
//     gulp.start('sass:watch');
// }));
```

to

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', 'sass:watch'));
```

I seriously doubt that gulp v4 supports `gulp.start`.

Also change to this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {   // added done here
    var files = [
        './*.html',
        './css/*.css',
        './img/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
        './js/*.js'
    ];

    browserSync.init(files, {
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
  done();                                    // called done() here
});
```

When I ran your code I noticed that the `sass:watch` task was never starting, hence you were not watching any files at all.  Here is what you should have seen in your terminal:

```
[21:26:21] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Test Bed\simple\gulpfile.js
[21:26:21] Starting 'default'...
[21:26:21] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[21:26:21] Finished 'browser-sync' after 164 ms
[21:26:21] Starting 'sass:watch'...         // this line missing when running your code
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.0.186:3000
 -----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

Don't be fooled by the last line, browser-sync always spits that out.  The reason why the `sass:watch` task was not starting was because gulp could never get past the `browser-sync` task - you have to signal gulp somehow that the task has completed and `done` is one way to do that.  Then gulp can go to the next task, which was `sass:watch`.  See [gulp: async completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback).

You also needed to make the change you noted in your comment `gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', gulp.series('scss'));`

There is nothing else wrong with your code - it runs perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. That worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad it worked - I just posted it!!  (Wouldn't mind the upvote ;>})

Answer (score 1):

Your Gulpfile isn't watching the sass files when changes are made. It's only looking for CSS changes. This is part of my Gulp task function to look for SCSS file changes

```
function serve() {
  browserSync.init({
    open: false,
    port: 8000,
    server: {
      baseDir: 'src/',
      index: 'index.html'
    },
  });
  gulp.watch(paths.scss.src, gulp.series([compileSCSS]));
}
```

And this is my SCSS compile function

```
function compileSCSS() {
  return gulp
    .src('./src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.rename('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'));
}
```

I have prepared a Gulp function with many required tools. You can check here
https://gist.github.com/choyan/ab034dc0539942ee0d8f0ab9788d790f

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I am a complete newbie in gulp, I am following an old tutorial and I can't understand what changes I shall do in my code. Can you point what changes I shall do in existing code in order to make it work?

Comment: I tried changing the line of  gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', ['sass']); to gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', gulp.series('scss'));  as I am using gulp 4. But still it won't work.

Comment: @Zahidul Watching `./css/*.scss` you probably didn't see the `*.scss` part.  So the watch is correct.